# how to add user input to array java?

Tags: java, arrays

So I have this project that requires me to generate a single dimensional array of user specified length and then have the user populate the array and I can't figure out what I'm supposed to do at the point where I'm at

```
import java.util.*;

public class singledimensionalarray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Please input array length: ");
        String[] SDArray= new String[keyboard.nextInt()];
        System.out.println("Please input " + SDArray.length + " double numbers:");
        int n = 0;
        for (n = 0; n <= SDArray.length; n++){
            SDArray.add (keyboard.nextDouble()); //keep getting an error here
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You have a `String` array, but you're asking for `Double` input.

Comment: I saw that after I posted

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import java.util.*;

public class singledimensionalarray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Please input array length: ");
        double[] SDArray= new double[keyboard.nextInt()];
        System.out.println("Please input " + SDArray.length + " double numbers:");
        for (int n = 0; n < SDArray.length; n++){
            SDArray[n] = (keyboard.nextDouble());
        }
        keyboard.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well first off do not write a for loop using n. Use the letter i. Second you are trying to store a double value inside a String array. What exactly does the user want to populate the array with?

EDIT: This is the only answer I have ever wrote. I was a sophomore in college and was not particularly well versed in java. Please for the love of Jesus unblock my account. I just spent a hour writing a well thought out answer only to have it blocked because of this single answer.

Comment: Is it a stylistic concern or a syntax one to not use n in a for loop? Also, the user has to populate it with doubles, I just realized the mistake with it being a string array.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so what I ended up doing is what Patrick and Khachik said; this is what I have

import java.util.*;

public class singledimensionalarray {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Please input array length: ");
    double[] SDArray= new double[keyboard.nextInt()];
    System.out.println("Please input " + SDArray.length + " double numbers:");
    for (int n = 0; n < SDArray.length; n++){
        SDArray[n] = (keyboard.nextDouble());
    }
    keyboard.close();
    System.out.print("After reversal:");
    for (int i = SDArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
         System.out.print(SDArray[i]+",");

}
```

}
}

Thanks for the help!